# ParseFloat goes NaN

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i have this code

```
function computeChange(){
var change;
var amountDue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountDue").value);
var amountReceive = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountReceive").value);
change = amountReceive - amountDue;
document.getElementById('amountChange').innerHTML = change;
}



<td>Total Amount</td>
<td>Php:<span id="amountDue"><?php echo $sum; ?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount Paid</td>
<td><input type="number" id="amountReceive" required="required" maxlength="4" size="4" onKeyUp="computeChange()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Change</td>
<td>Php:<span id="amountChange"></span></td>
</tr>
```

on the total amount is a decimal
on the amount paid input type=text

So the problem is if i enter something in the text box the span on change goes `NaN`

Comment: what is entered into the textbox?

Comment: `amountDue` is a `span`, it doesn't have value.

Comment: @DanielA.White THE AMOUNT RECEIVED is entered if you enter it it will trigger the span to diplay values

Comment: @zerkms it will display a value once i enter something into textbox

Comment: @Mowgli Mecha IV: you don't understand - `span` DOM element doesn't have `.value` attribute. Only input fields have.

Answer (score 9):

```
parseFloat( document.getElementById("amountDue").value );
```

is technically equivalent to

```
parseFloat( undefined );
```

which yields the value `NaN` because span elements do not have a property named `.value`. Maybe you wanted `.innerHTML`?

```
parseFloat( document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML );
```

Answer (score 5):

`#amountDue` is a `<span>` element, so it does not have a `value` property.

Use `.innerHTML` to get its contents.

```
var amountDue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not return you the value:

```
      document.getElementById("amountDue").value
```

as `amountDue` is not a HTML input element.

Try below:

```
     document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML;
```

i.e.

```
    var amountDue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` of amountDue is returning `undefined`, causing the parseFloat to return `NaN`
Use `innerHTML` instead. Change this row

```
var amountDue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountDue").value);
```

to

```
var amountDue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML);
```